# What is $1+2+4+8+16+...+2^n$?

Tags: summation, power-series

What is the result of:

summation from one, two, four, eight until $n$ power of two?

Thank you!

Comment: What is 2S with relation to S?

Comment: It is $2^{n+1}-1$...

Answer (score 5):

In binary you get the number $\underbrace{11\dots 11}_n$ which is the number that goes before $\underbrace{100\dots 00}_{n+1}=2^{n+1}$

Comment: Neat.$\text{}\text{}$

Comment: I like it! Simple yet effective

Comment: A refreshing way to look at it! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
S&=1+2+4+\dotsb+2^n\\
1+S&=1+1+2+4+\dotsb+2^n\\
&=2+2+4+\dotsb+2^n\\
&=4+4+\dotsb+2^n\\
&=8+\dotsb+2^n\\
&\dotsb\\
&=2^n+2^n\\
1+S&=2^{n+1}\\
S&=2^{n+1}-1
\end{align}
Write it out for a specific example to understand this better.

Answer (score 1):

One can write $$S=1+2+\cdots+2^n,$$ and note that $$S=2S-S.$$ Hence, since $$2S=2(1+2+\cdots+2^n)=2+4+\cdots+2^{n+1}=S-1+2^{n+1},$$ we have $$S=2S-S=S-1+2^{n+1}-S=2^{n+1}-1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a GP with ratio $2$
Having $n+1$ terms

So the sum will be
$$\frac{1\{2^{(n+1)}-1\}}{(2-1)}= 2^{(n+1)}-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ this sum, then by difference of $2S$ and $S$ we have:
\begin{array}{cccccc}
2S&=& & &2&+&4&+&8&+&\ldots&+&2^n&+&2^{n+1}\\
-S&=&-1&-&2&-&4&-&8&-&\ldots&-&2^n&\\
\hline
S&=&-1&+&0&+&0&+&0&+&\ldots&+&0&+&2^{n+1}\\
\end{array}
Hence, $$\boxed{\color{blue}{S=2^{n+1}-1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another answer. Your sum is:

$$\sum_{j=0}^n2^j=\frac{1}{2}(2)\sum_{j=0}^n2^j$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^n2^j(2)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^n2^{j+1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} 2^k$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\left(-2^0+2^0+\sum_{k=1}^n2^k+2^{n+1}\right)$$
$$2\sum_{j=0}^n2^j=\sum_{k=0}^n2^k+2^{n+1}-2^0$$
$$\sum_{j=0}^n2^j=2^{n+1}-1$$